# Qt Stylesheet syntax: targeting a specific button, not ALL buttons

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets

I have a window with two buttons.

I'd like to decorate each one with a different stylesheet. They both have different object names, of course, but it seems that only the generic `QPushButton` stylesheet selector works.

I tried:

```
QPushButton#myBtnObjectName1 {

/* style definitions */

}
QPushButton#myBtnObjectName2 {

/* style definitions */

}
```

Tried the same with replacing the `#` with a `.`, or having the `#myBtnObjetNameX` only. Nothing works. Just:

```
QPushButton {
/* style definitions */
}
```

Am I using a wrong syntax? Or is this simply impossible without deriving from `QPushButton` in code and using a separate class name for each?

Comment: Do I have to define the object name someplace OTHER than the "ObjectName" in QT-Designer?

Comment: it is important how and where exactly you apply the stylesheet?

Comment: during construction:  QFile file(stylesheetURL);
    file.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
    QString styleSheet = QLatin1String(file.readAll());
    setStyleSheet(styleSheet);

Comment: on some widget(which one) or application wide(QApplication)?

Comment: #objectName seems to work fin in Qt 5.8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah yes, the "AccessibleName" in Qt Designer needs to be set too, not just "ObjectName"

Comment: There is something unusual there. I can create a QWidget with two QPushButtons on it using Qt Designer and select each button by name using the selector QPushButton#button_name in a css style sheet assigned to the QWidget giving both buttons different background colors. It works correctly (for me) without needing to set anything for AccessibleName.

Comment: I am using 4.7.1 I believe. I apply the stylesheet in the constructor of the widget.

Answer (score 10):

To match instances using the `objectName`, you can also use the selector `^=`. According to the [standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#attribute-selectors):

> [att^=val] Represents an element with the att attribute whose value
>   begins with the prefix "val".

Example in Qt:

```
QPushButton[objectName^="push"] { background-color: red; }
```

A `QPushButton` called `pushButton` would be matched, but not an object called `pbt`.

Answer (score 8):

You can use "accessibleName" in Qt Designer for this.
And in qss stylesheet:

more universal:

```
[accessibleName="alert-error"] {
    color: red;
}
```

or be more specific:

```
QPushButton[accessibleName="bigred"] {
   background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: I think this is a bad idea because it makes your app harder to use for people relying on the accessible name.