# QT StyleSheet Theme for entire application using attribute selectors

Tags: c++, css, qt, qwidget, qtstylesheets

**Background:**

I have a Qt application consisting of multiple dialogs and windows. I am trying to condense all styles into a single stylesheet which I want to load in my `main.cpp` with the aim of it being applied to my whole application (as I understand one should do). *The application should not change styles from this point onwards.*

I want to do this as styles can get mixed up, etc if one does [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#style-sheet-usage) or something simliar for each widget in the QtCreator designer.

**Problem:**

*I will explain a specific problem I face with an example from my application.*

I have a couple of variations of simple dialogs, QLabel title, QLabel message (sometimes a QLabel hint), and either a single 'ok' QPushButton or 2 QPushButtons 'positive' & 'negative'.

For my theme, I would like to set styles for specific buttons, labels, etc which I got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4925184/qt-stylesheet-syntax-targeting-a-specific-button-not-all-buttons).

**Example CSS:**

```
QPushButton {
    font-size: 10pt
    color: #111
} 

QPushButton[objectName="btnPostive"][objectName="btnProceed"] {
    font-size: 1pt
    color: #ccc
} 

QLabel {
    font-size: 9pt
    color: #111
} 

QLabel[objectName="lblTitle"] {
    font-size: 9pt
    color: #111
}
```

*Please note, the `[objectName="btnPostive"][objectName="btnProceed"]` is intended to apply the style to buttons with the `objectName`'s `btnPostive` and `btnProceed` however, it does not.*

Is what I intend doing considered best practice, and a sub question (preferred example too) applying the same style to a select group of widgets, how should one best  this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to control the applied stylesheet based on the object name, you can use the *ID Selector* `QPushButton#objectName`, see the full [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types]).  You separate multiple objects with the same stylesheet with a `,`

Your stylesheet should then be this.  Please note that you also need a `;` at the end of each line.

```css
QPushButton {
    font-size: 10pt;
    color: #111;
} 

QPushButton#btnPositive, QPushButton#btnProceed {
    font-size: 1pt;
    color: #ccc;
} 

QLabel {
    font-size: 9pt;
    color: #111;
} 

QLabel#lblTitle {
    font-size: 9pt;
    color: #00f;
}
```